# Как сделать загрузку сразу нескольких изображений

Tags: php

Есть код, который осуществляет загрузку изображений на сервер:

```
if (@$_REQUEST['Upload']) { 

$data = $_FILES['file']; 

$tmp = $data['tmp_name']; 

if (@file_exists($tmp)) { 
$info = @getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
if (preg_match('{image/(.*)}is', $info['mime'], $p)) { 




  $name = "$imgDir/".$kw.".".$p[1]; 

  function watermark($file, $watermark) { //водяной знак для фото

if(empty($file) | empty($watermark)) return false;

 $wh = getimagesize($watermark);
 $fh = getimagesize($file);
 $rwatermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark); 
 $rfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

  imagecopy($rfile, $rwatermark, $fh[0] - $wh[0], $fh[1] - $wh[1], 0, 0, $wh[0], $wh[1]);
  imagejpeg($rfile, $file, '80'); 
  imagedestroy($rwatermark);
  imagedestroy($rfile);

 return true;

}



  move_uploaded_file($tmp, $name);
  $newfile = ''.$name.'';
  watermark($newfile, './waterMark.png'); //ложим водяной знак на фото



 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `photo` (`idWork`, `name`, `ras`) values('$idWork', '$kw', '$p[1]')");  //запись о фото в базу

  header("Location: /work/$wwoooRK[url]");
  exit;
}
```

Форма для выбора фото:

```
<form action="/upf.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="submit" name="Upload" class="button" value="Загрузить"> 
</form>
```

Делал форму так:

```
<form action="/upf.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="file" name="file"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Upload" class="button" value="Загрузить"> 
</form>
```

Но добавляет только одно фото. 
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай так

```
<form action="/upf.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="file[]"><br />
<input type="file" name="file[]"><br />
<input type="file" name="file[]"><br />
<input type="file" name="file[]"><br />
<input type="file" name="file[]"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Upload" class="button" value="Загрузить"> 
</form>
```

Comment: в таком случаем код загрузки ведет себя так, как будто я не выбрал файлы для загрузки

Comment: @Денис у Вас будет передаваться массив имен, сделайте на обработчика `var_dump($_FILES);` и все поймете

Comment: теперь выводит инфу о всех загружаемых фото... но они не сохранются(( не могли бы вы помочь мне с этим? не могу понять как сохранить их все на сервер

Answer (score 0):

**multiple**

```
<input type="file" name="photo" multiple title="Загрузите одну или несколько фотографий">
```

http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/multiple

Comment: В вопросе тег [tag:php], а не [tag:html]. Так что, вероятно, это не совсем ответ.